# Filtering based on value and creating list in spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and I am trying to do the following, using Pyspark:

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, `"id", "number1", "number2"`.

For each value of `"id"` I have multiple rows and what I want to do is create a list of tuples with all the rows that correspond to each id.

Eg, for the following dataframe

```
id | number1 | number2 |
a  |       1 |       1 |
a  |       2 |       2 |
b  |       3 |       3 |
b  |       4 |       4 |
```

the desired outcome would be 2 lists as such:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

and

```
[(3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

I'm not sure how to approach this, since I'm a newbie. I have managed to get a list of the distinct ids doing the following

```
distinct_ids = [x for x in df.select('id').distinct().collect()]
```

In pandas that I'm more familiar with, now I would loop through the dataframe for each distinct id and gather all the rows for it, but I'm sure this is far from optimal.

Can you give me any ideas? `Groupby` comes to mind but I'm not sure how to approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and aggregate using `collect_list` and `array`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list(F.array('number1', 'number2')).alias('number'))

df2.show()
+---+----------------+
| id|          number|
+---+----------------+
|  b|[[3, 3], [4, 4]]|
|  a|[[1, 1], [2, 2]]|
+---+----------------+
```

And if you want to get back a list of tuples,

```
result = [[tuple(j) for j in i] for i in [r[0] for r in df2.select('number').orderBy('number').collect()]]
```

which gives `result` as `[[(1, 1), (2, 2)], [(3, 3), (4, 4)]]`

If you want a numpy array, you can do

```
result = np.array([r[0] for r in df2.select('number').collect()])
```

which gives

```
array([[[3, 3],
        [4, 4]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

Comment: Thanks very much @mck!! Can the same thing be done to create an array of arrays?

Comment: @TheDeC what do you mean? What is the output that you want?

Comment: The same, but result could be an array of arrays, instead of a list of lists. I found a workaround, but it would be nice to know how this can be done from the start.

Comment: There is no array in Python @TheDeC . Did you mean numpy arrays?

Comment: I mean, in the same format as np.asarray()

Comment: Yes, excuse me.